# Is it an anti-pattern to use Jackson's `@JsonCreator` on empty constructors?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I repeatedly saw code like the following, where the empty constructor was deleted by well-intentioned developers (because it appeared unused), which then broke Jackson serialization (caught by tests later on):

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  
  // appears unused – only used by Jackson
  public Person() {}

  // used in code
  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking of adding a `@JsonCreator` annotation to the empty constructor to make it more obvious that the constructor is used by Jackson to prevent developers from removing it:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  
  @JsonCreator // <--------
  public Person() {}

  // used in code
  public Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Is this a good idea or does this have unintended consequences (i. e. changing semantics compared to the no-annotation case)?

Or is this use of `@JsonCreator` an anti-pattern and there is a better way to achieve this (short of converting the class to a record)?

Comment: I'd recommend just using a comment to avoid unexpected side effects

Comment: I don't find it an anti-pattern at all.  It succinctly documents the purpose of the empty constructor, but more importantly, IDEs such as IntelliJ can be easily configured to stop warning about unused constructors (and methods, fields, etc) when a specific annotation is present.  Regardless of whether your tests *should* have caught this, catching it sooner than tests has value.

Comment: @ControlAltDel the comments haven't worked out, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: "Create unit/integration tests and force pull/merge requests run these tests" would be a better approach.

Comment: That's already being done. 
I'm asking this question because I prefer preventing mistakes to finding out about them after running tests.

Answer (score 0):

Reading more documentation about this I and regarding all the comments to the question and other answer(s) I came to the conclusion that it really is an anti-pattern to use the `@JsonCreator` for the default constructor.

The Javadoc (e.g. [from version 2.13](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html)) specifies that a ctor annotated with that annotation should have at least one parameter. (It doesn't explicitly say so, but a ctor without arguments would be useless more or less.)

> NOTE: when annotating creator methods (constructors, factory methods), method must either be:
>
> - Single-argument constructor/factory method without JsonProperty annotation for the argument: if so, this is so-called "delegate creator", in which case Jackson first binds JSON into type of the argument, and then calls creator. This is often used in conjunction with JsonValue (used for serialization).
> - Constructor/factory method where every argument is annotated with either JsonProperty or JacksonInject, to indicate name of property to bind to

So for your problem I would suggest that you get rid of the default ctor and instead annotate at least one of the remaining ctor(s) used in code as well properly. Jackson can use that and the IDE will not mark it as unused.

It also could save you from workarounds for not properly or completely initialized objects.

In your example this could be

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  @JsonCreator
  public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  // other getters / setters / business logic come here

}
```

Comment: You convinced me @Bohemian ;), but I wanted to give more advice how to solve the OPs problem.

Comment: The documentation not mentioning the behavior of `@JsonCreator` on empty parameter lists is actually a very good point.

Comment: As it's legal to not explicitly initalize all fields in an `@JsonCreator` annotated ctor, I would think that the behavior of such a default ctor is no different from a plain one: Simply would init all fields with individual setters.

But doesn't bring you forward with your goal - you also could simply annotate such a ctor with a `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` for the same effect in the IDE and being more concise about your intention to other developers - especially if you add a human readable comment why you placed the suppression. Still no compiler warning if you delete it

Answer (score -1):

It's an anti pattern, because the default constructor is the `@JsonCreator` default and everyone knows it - it is useless code.

You don't need to *prevent developers from removing it* because your functional tests will fail if they do so.

Comment: I prefer preventing mistakes, not finding out about them after running tests.

Comment: @soc but you run tests locally before pushing.

Comment: Yes, and .....?

Comment: @soc best practice has you frequently running the build+test (which typically completes in a couple of minutes) locally - essentially after every small chunk of coding work. In the unlikely, and at most one time per dev, event that a dev deletes the default constructor, within a few minutes that change will cause a test to fail. I've been in this situation many times: relying on test for this kind of stuff works great. Putting an annotation there, or even a comment (and comments are nowadays an anti-pattern), does not stop anyone from deleting the constructor, so you *need* tests anyway.

Comment: See first comment.

Comment: @soc putting an annotation on a constructor does **not** prevent a dev deleting that constructor. You still need functional tests, ideally ones that can be run locally on the dev's machine, to catch such problems before they are merged into the code base and deployed.

Comment: There are functional tests. The problem is caught with tests.

Comment: @Bohemian if everybody would adhere to "best practices", this problem would not have popped up at all - but with many humans working on code, human errors will happen. (Best practice also would be to check thoroughly before you just remove code and ensure with tests that the removal is harmless.)

Comment: @cyberbrain Agreed! The motivation is not that the issue is not being caught (it is), the motivation is that I want to catch and avoid mistakes earlier in the pipeline. I don't quite understand why Bohemian is trying to provide an answer if he hasn't grasped the question.

Comment: @soc I grasp what you are saying perfectly. I just disagree. Having successfully lead many teams and projects, I strongly advocate a) you should never write code you don’t need, and b) copious tests are what keeps your code bug free and always deployable, not pseudo-comment code. Reiterating, adding an annotation to a constructor that isn’t used by the code base does **not** prevent its deletion.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a case of "those who can, do, those who can't, lead", but *documenting intent* goes a long way in most code bases. Annotations *are* pseudo-comments with added benefit that the IDE can help and find all usages, which it can't do with arbitrary comments. It's more a question of inventing my own "pseduo-comment" like `@UsedByJackson` or using one of the library-provided "pseudo-comments" if there are no drawbacks (like changed semantics).

Comment: @soc ouch. Annotating the constructor will **not** help the IDE find usages - json serialisation usages will be invisible to the IDE/dev regardless of annotations/comments/anything. Nevertheless, `@UsedByJackson`, `@JsonCreator` or `// DO NOT DELETE` comments are all anti patterns because they do not stop the code from being deleted. Worse, they may in harm the project because at some point the correct thing to do may be to delete the constructor (due to some refactoring or whatever) and these "keep me" code markers will suddenly no longer be valid, creating confusion and friction to the dev.